# Python matplotlib - how to pick a darker color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, networkx

I am using Networkx to plot my network. I have a problem for choosing colors. the colors picked are often very light which is not good given the background color is white (see below example). is there a way to pickup the darker color to make the graph more clear and visible.

[image]

below is my code for choosing colors:

```
def PickupColor():
    color=random.choice(list(matplotlib.colors.cnames.items()))[0]
    return color
```

Comment: as you are calling a random function on matplotlib colors, so it can give you any color. one way is to define your own list of colors and then pick any or if works can remove color with 'light' on it, pls note this will not be a sound solution though as you can still get white color. `color = random.choice([each_color for each_color in list(matplotlib.colors.cnames.items()) 
                           if "light" not in each[0]])[0]`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many colours you need. You can see a list of the supported colour names [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html). Note the XKCD colours are mentioned, but aren't explicitly shown.

If all you need is 10-20 at most (otherwise I could see your graphs getting extremely dense), I would handpick them and then select from that list.

```
colors = ['black', 'gray', 'brown', 'red', ...]
```

Needless to say, other than filtering for darker colours, there are pairs that are almost indistinguishable and I would choose one or the other. For example, darkred-maroon, navy-darkblue, firebrick-crimson, etc.

Another issue with your colour selection is that each time you need a colour you pick one with replacement. So it's possible two chains will have the same one. It would be better to fetch in advance how many colours you'll need with [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

---

Anecdotal story: Once I animated a horizontal barchart of 200 items, which changed ranks constantly (showed only top 10). I assigned them a unique colour by generating 6 equidistant numbers in the range 0-255 and combining that for the RGB channels I could get up to 6**3 = 216 colours. I quickly realised how many colours looked similar.

If you really need a lot of colours, you could generate them algorithmically in some manner and as long as at least one of RGB is less than 128 in value, they should be dark enough. But really, unless absolutely necessary, just handpick a few distinct ones and call it a day.